# Unexpected MYSQL syntax error

Tags: mysql

I tried to create the SP using the code from the url below  , however it display many syntax error.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html

```
CREATE PROCEDURE curdemo()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE a CHAR(16);
  DECLARE b, c INT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id,data FROM test.t1;
  DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR SELECT i FROM test.t2;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;
  OPEN cur2;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO a, b;
    FETCH cur2 INTO c;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    IF b < c THEN
      INSERT INTO test.t3 VALUES (a,b);
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO test.t3 VALUES (a,c);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
  CLOSE cur2;
END;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: INT DEFAULT FALSE;
this is the reason for syntax error
change this to INT DEFAULT 0;

Comment: Change the delimiter before your procedure. For instance like this: `delimiter ||`

Comment: @ ocks, please see  my second pic.

Comment: @ juergen d, sorry I cannot understand , how to Change the delimiter before your procedure?

Comment: @juergen d , can you give me the details steps?

Comment: check the sample how to use delimiter 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html

Answer (score 1):

Change your delimiter first

```
delimiter ||
CREATE PROCEDURE curdemo()
BEGIN
 ...
END
||
delimiter ;
```

Otherwise the DB engine thinks your procedure definitions ends at the first `;` which would make it incomplete.

Comment: great , successfully after adding the delimiter ||.